# Stupid question - why can't interval covers of a dense nullset be expanded to arbitrarily small covers of the real line?

Tags: measure-theory

So we all know that the rational numbers are dense, meaning that for any positive real, however small, there's one within that distance of any given real number, and we all know that their collection has measure zero, meaning that for any positive real, there exists a countable set of intervals that contains every rational number whose lengths add up to less than that real.

So here's my question: given such a set for a given real, if you were to broaden the first interval by that real, then the next by half, the next by a fourth, the next by an eighth, and so on - since the rationals are dense, wouldn't every real number fall into one of those intervals?  But you'd only be tripling the measure of the cover.

(I know this is a stupid question.  I await a stupid answer.)

Comment: You will cover more irrationals, more in the sense of the increase in length in the cover. Still there are irrationals for which the intervals covering the rationals in any of its neighborhoods would need a larger increase in length in order to cover that irrational.

Comment: I think that broadening a cover is a bit of a red herring. Why does the cover not hit every real number in the first place?

Comment: It's not a stupid question. Alon Amit has a good answer here: https://www.quora.com/When-proving-that-the-rationals-have-measure-zero-why-does-this-not-also-prove-that-the-reals-have-measure-zero-given-that-any-open-cover-of-the-rationals-is-also-a-cover-of-the-reals

Comment: Just so you are clear, because there are answers down there talking about compactness and what not. The reason why you can't still cover is purely measure theoretical. If your countable union of measurable sets has measure less than the whole space, then they don't cover the whole space. This is because it contradicts monotonicity of the measure (a consequence of $\sigma$-aditivity and positivity of the measure). The reason why you might think that it could cover is a confusion on what dense means. Dense implies a finite cover with *closed* sets covers the space, not open sets.

Comment: @treeleaf Good of you to clarify that this is all purely measure theoretical. Now tell us, how do you prove that the Lebesgue measure of $\Bbb R$ is strictly positive, without compactness and whatnot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a closed interval eg $[0,3]$, which is compact. Suppose the intervals surrounding the rationals cover this whole interval - this is an open cover and has a finite subcover by compactness. But if the intervals have length $\frac 12, \frac 14 \dots \frac 1{2^n} \dots$ the total length of a finite subset is less than $1$.

Try constructing a cover of the rationals which avoids $\sqrt 2$ as an exercise to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Let be $\Bbb Q = \{q_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and $\{(q_n - 1/2^n,q_n + 1/2^n)\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ the cover.

The fact is that for some (*many*!) "rebel" real number $x_0$:
$$\forall n\in\Bbb N: |x_0 - q_n|\ge 1/2^n.$$
Having many rational numbers arbitrarily near of $x_0$ does not mean that *some concrete* rational number is as near of $x_0$ as you want.

Comment: First off, I'm pretty sure that in your last sentence you mean "real," not "rational."  But my point is, isn't every real an arbitrarily small distance from a rational?  It's not a matter of "many," it's a matter of "small."

Comment: @user361424, I'm taking $\Bbb Q$ as *example* of dense set "small" in the measure sense. And yes, every real is at an arbitrarily small distance from *some* rational, but not *the rational that you want*.